# Firefox: Hide about:newtab in tab history

Tags: firefox, history, browser-tabs, tabs

When I open a new tab, it defaults to about:newtab. When I then enter a URL in the address bar and go to it, about:newtab appears in the tab's history. This started happening in Firefox 57. I don't want about:newtab to appear in the tab's history. How can I revert this behavior?

Comment: Try upgrading to Firefox 58. Does clicking the 3 dots, and remove from history not work?

Comment: Then I'd have to do that every time though. And I don't see that option in the three dots (in the address bar) anyway. I prefer it like before, because then I could see if I was on the first page in the tab, by checking if the back button was greyed out.

Comment: Are you using Windows? You may wish to provide a screenshot because I cannot reproduce the behavior...

Comment: The question is not asking about Firefox history, but the entries that appear for the Back/Forward buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: go into about:config and set browser.newtabpage.activity-stream.enabled to false.

More detailed walkthrough here: https://www.howtogeek.com/333805/how-to-change-or-customize-firefoxs-new-tab-page/